# Is it possible to add a "whats new" text while publishing via visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, publish

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and i would like to display a "whats new" text to my users whenever they get the dialog to install the updated version of the published application. Is it possible to do this in visual studio?